# passing char* of structure via namedpipe in c++

Tags: c++, pipe

i am trying to pass structure through Named Pipe ,but at receiving end ,i am not able to got "address" data which is a `char *` placed inside `structure` . by using `WriteFile()`,`ReadFile()`
following are requirements:

1. pass a char pointer which resides into structure .
2. and want to communicate between systems over a network

Thank you all

Comment: I am unclear on the meaning of "address data which is a char *". You are not trying to pass a memory pointer between two distinct applications, are you?

Answer (score 1):

You can not move pointers between systems. Your structure field should either have:

1) Fixed sized char array:

```
struct {
  /* ... */
  char data[256]; 
};
```

2) Variable sized data at the end of structure:

```
struct {
  /* ... */
  size_t size;
  char data[0]; // data follows...
};
```

Comment: "You can not move pointers between systems" Can i am able to access pointer between different processes of same system

Comment: how and explain it :-2) Variable sized data at the end of structure

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to serialise / deserialise the structure at either end. C and C++ if those are what you are using - I don't recall ReadFile/WriteFile being in either of those languages) don't support serialising structures of themselves, and you'll have to write code to do it.

Thus

```
struct { int a; int b; char *c; } s;
fwrite(pipe, &s.a, sizeof(a));
fwrite(pipe, &s.b, sizeof(a));
int c = strlen(s.c);
fwrite(pipe, &c, sizeof(c));
fwrite(pipe, s.c, c);
```

Note: This is NOT a good, portable and reslient way of doing this. It's just a way of doing it.

Comment: can you tell me ,how to serialise a c++ structure or class

Comment: you write out all the members of the struct/class in a way that can be read at the other end. in particular, this means if you have a pointer, you have to write out what the pointer points to.